# JSONP Response from Python Django

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

I am trying to return a JSONP object from a django view by appending the callback to the response as below:

```
def complete(request):
    prefix = request.GET.get('q','')
    mode = request.GET.get('mode','')
    callback = request.GET.get('callback', '')

    response = completer_func(prefix, inv_indices, trie)
    if callback != None:
        response = '{0}({1})'.format(callback, response)

    return JsonResponse(response, safe=False)
```

which returns something like `"jQuery11110037170758636331014_1499222434194([u'information technology', u'interior design', u'international', u'industrial design', u'information technology services'])"` when I check the response under inspect/network in chrome. However, at the client side, it is throwing an error, which I logged to the console and shows that

```
readyState: 4
demo.html:91 responseText: undefined
demo.html:92 status: 200
demo.html:93 text status: parsererror
demo.html:94 error: Error: jQuery11110037170758636331014_1499222434194 was not called
```

I saw a couple of other posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11574850/jsonp-web-service-with-python) explaining how one should add the callback to the response (which I did). But somehow it doesn't seem to work. I have included the jquery ajax call below

```
$('#ajax-demo').autoComplete({
                minChars: 1,
                source: function(term, response){
                  $.ajax({
                    dataType: "jsonp",
                    type: "GET",
                    url: 'http://localhost:8000/complete/',
                    data: {
                      q: term
                    },
                    success: function (data) {


                    },
                    error: function(xhr,textStatus,err){
                      console.log("readyState: " + xhr.readyState);
                      console.log("responseText: "+ xhr.responseText);
                      console.log("status: " + xhr.status);
                      console.log("text status: " + textStatus);
                      console.log("error: " + err);
                    }
                  });
                }
            });
```

### Update 1

I was able to fix this problem following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35535102/937153) answer and allowing CORS headers at my server side and using JSON instead of JSONP. But I am still wondering what was wrong in my first approach.

Comment: try to return a simple `json` and validate if it is the json which is messing up or something else, something like `{"title": "Person","type": "object"}`

Comment: I started from there! But trying to return `json` gives the CORS error: `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource`

Comment: @Unni Try just loading the URL directly in your browser first before getting it to work from JavaScript.

Comment: @MichaelMior: I did that actually! Seems to be working fine.

Comment: @Unni Is that also true in the JSONP case? If so, sounds like a JS problem.