# Angular app can't read Django Rest Framework API because of CORS issue

Tags: python, angular, django-rest-framework, cors

I'm experiencing a CORS issue consuming a Django Rest Framework REST API from an Angular 6 app.

The API runs on http://localhost:55098/admin. It works fine when I invoke it with Insomnia. Angular app runs on http://localhost:4200.

When I first typed http://localhost:4200/cgestores it should redirect to http://localhost:55098/admin/cgestores, and it did, but I got a CORS error message (see below).

My configuration:

**REST API**: I'm using Python 3.7 (64 bit), Django (2.1.5) and Django Rest Framework (3.9.1)

My settings.py:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
    'testserver',
    'localhost'
    ]

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # Add your apps here to enable them
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework_swagger',
    'corsheaders',
    'admin_v20',
]

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

**Angular client**: I'm using Angular 6.4.1. The service (apiusuarios.service.ts):

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpErrorResponse, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class ApiusuariosService {

  datos: iCentroGestor;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getMock(): any{
    return [
      {"gececo":"a", "gecdes":"one"},
      {"gececo":"b", "gecdes":"two"},
      {"gececo":"c", "gecdes":"three"}
    ];
  }

  getUsers(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(endpoint + 'cgestores').pipe(map(this.extractData));
  }

}

export interface iCentroGestor {
  gececo: string;
  gecdes: string;
}

const endpoint = 'http://localhost:55098/admin/';
```

Method `getMock()` returns a fixed JSON value just for test purposes, and it works fine. The method that actually calls the API is `getUsers()`, and is the method that triggers the CORS error:

**Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:55098/admin/cgestores/' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.**

(that's Chrome; Firefox and Edge return similar responses)

This seemed to be an issue for a lot of people, I checked these articles:

- https://github.com/crs4/ome_seadragon/wiki/Enable-Django-CORS-(Cross-Origin-Resource-Sharing)-Headers-configuration
- https://www.techiediaries.com/django-cors/
- [CORS django 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35521935/cors-django-access-control-allow-origin)
- [No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' using django rest framework api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49519850/no-access-control-allow-origin-using-django-rest-framework-api)
- [Django Python rest framework, No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource in chrome, works in firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43357687/django-python-rest-framework-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present)
- [Django Rest Framework: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://127.0.0.1:8000/xyz/api/abc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33375797/django-rest-framework-xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-http-127-0-0-18000-xyz-api/33377351#33377351)

...and a few more, and also this video:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OIbndrrUYiY

...and they all pretty much sayed the same: it's not an Angular problem, it's a server issue, and I should make the following modifications to my DRF project:

1. Install CORS headers package
2. Modify settings.py with the following:

   - Add CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST
   - Add corsheaders to INSTALLED_APPS
   - Add corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware to MIDLEWARE_CLASSES

All done, but it still didn't work. After trying all that, I read that I could specify the header that I need on my response. So I tried this in my DRF project:

```
return Response(data=pDatos, status=pStatus, headers={"Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*"})
```

... and bingo, it worked!

However, this is not really a solution, I don't like to have to depend on a specific parameter on a specific response. And, on top of that, I have no way to restrict who can access the site and who can't, which would be really easy to do with CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST (well, I could, but writing a parameter with a list of sites in place of the asterisk symbol doesn't seem to be the right option).

So, what am I doing wrong? Why do my `settings.py` options not work? I commented them out, and just left the `return Response...` and it still works, so `settings.py` is not really doing anything.

Sorry for this long post. Any ideas? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: If at some point you have flushed your database, you may need to create the _CorsModel_ model table again: `manage.py makemigrations corsheaders; manage.py migrate corsheaders`.

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2017. I used the `Make migrations...` and `Migrate` context menu options to apply any pending changes, but it didn't detect any. Still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer myself, I'd like to share it.

I'm using Django 2.1.5. It appears that section `MIDDLEWARE_CLASS` is simply called `MIDDLEWARE` since version 2. When I changed it I was forced to comment out `django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticacionMiddleware`, and that did the magic. Now everything works as it should.

Comment: I've been with the exact same problem for two hours. Thanks for saving me !!!

Answer (score 6):

Start by installing django-cors-headers using pip

```
pip install django-cors-headers
```

You need to add it to your project settings.py file:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ##...
    'corsheaders'
)
```

Next you need to add corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware middleware to the middleware classes in settings.py

```
MIDDLEWARE = (
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    #...
)
```

You can then, either enable CORS for all domains by adding the following setting

```
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
```

Or Only enable CORS for specified domains:

```
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = False

CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
    'http://localhost:8000', # Allowed host, if CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL is False
)
```

Comment: Django 5: CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = (
    'http://localhost:4200',
    
    # COMA AFTER 1 entry
)